# C program to take integer if it is Prime or Not Prime

Tags: c, integer, primes, long-integer

I have this C program codes are completely and it's works very well, but not the correct result. I have them code source here in the below. Can anyone help me what is going on or what did I missing? Everyone are welcome to correct this English or code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;
  int result;

  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf ("Usage: p4 <number>\n");
    }
  n = atoi (argv[1]);

  if (n < 2)
    {
      printf ("input number should be > 1\n");
    }
  result = isprime (n);

  if (result == 1)
    printf ("%d is prime\n", n);
  else
    printf ("%d is not prime\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

I made a function called isprime that returns true (i.e. 1) if the integer number passed to it is prime and false (i.e. 0) if it is composite (i.e. not prime.)  A number is composite if it is divisible by 2 or any odd number up to the square root of the number itself, otherwise it is prime. After I programmed it, the output isn't what I expected the reference.

> Compiled:
>
> ```
> p4:
> -Output of program (p4) is not correct for input '9872349871':
> ------ Yours: ------
> 1282415279 is not prime
> ---- Reference: ----
> 9872349871 is not prime
> --------------------
> ```

Comment: You may wish to compare the number in the output with the maximum value an integer can hold on your platform (`INT_MAX`).

Comment: Where should be for ('INT_MAX')?

Comment: You can write a simple program in C that calls `printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);`.

Comment: #include <limits.h>

Comment: I think the question is whether the _input_ is too big for an integer, not the output.

Comment: Devin Morlan, What is the largest value your code must handle?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the input value, 9872349871, is too large to fit into a 32-bit integer.

You need to rewrite the program to use `long long` instead of `int` (this should give you a 64-bit integer) and in order to parse the command line parameter you will want to switch `atoi` to `atoll`.

*Caveat*: If your `isprime` implementation (which wasn't shown in the question) avoids the square root check (`a <= sqrt(b)`) by multiplying a value by itself (`a*a <= b`), that squared value may overflow the limits of even a 64-bit integer. So you may need to revise that function, *e.g.* with `a <= b/a`.

Comment: You're right, and for some reason I got my logic completely backwards on that. Otherwise we'd think 9 was prime

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your test case '9872349871' is too large to be held in an int (on your implementation / machine).

A simple fix is this (changed everything to long, **used strtol to catch out-of-range problems**):

EDIT: Depending on your compiler, long might not be large enough for your sample input. long long indeed is guaranteed to be 8 bytes, but will only work on compilers that at least support C99.

**The really important part is to check your input value! Otherwise your code is not one bit safer than before.**

```
char *end;
long n = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
if(errno == ERANGE){
    printf("The number you entered is too large!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

//OK, so this is a sloppy, inefficient implementation.

/*
int isprime(long n) {
   for (long i = 2; i != n; ++i)
     if (n%i == 0)
        return 0;
   return 1;
} */


// A better one:
int isprime(long n) {
   if(n <= 3)
      return n >= 2;
   if(n%2 == 0)
      return 0;

  for (long i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)
     if (n%i == 0)
         return 0;
  return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc < 2)
   {
       printf ("Usage: p4 <number>\n");
       return -1;
   }

   char *end;
   long n = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
   if(errno == ERANGE){
      printf("The number you entered is too large!\n");
      return -1;
   }
   if (n < 2)
   {
      printf ("input number should be > 1\n");
      return -1;
   }
   int result = isprime(n);

   if (result == 1)
     printf ("%ld is prime\n", n);
   else
     printf ("%ld is not prime\n", n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: For large prime `n`, `for (long i = 2; i <= n/i; ++i)` is significantly faster than `for (long i = 2; i != n; ++i)`.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to focus on the range problem without adding further problems for the OP.

Comment: OP has "A number is composite if it is divisible by 2 or any odd number up to the square root of the number itself, otherwise it is prime" so suggesting going up to `n` instead of the square root of `n` adds problems.

Comment: @chux While the OP did not ask for implementation help, I still think that it is irrelevant in that respect. On the other hand I do agree that one should not post unnecessarily sloppy code. Hope you like the reworked implementation better.

Comment: Re-worked code algorithm is a good performance improvement.  Issues remain.  `abs(n)` certainly should be `labs(n)` for `long n`. `if(abs(n) == 1) return 0;` test is of unclear usefulness.  When`n<0`, why look at -1?  Other odds like -3 die on `sqrt(n)`.  I'd expect all `n<0` to return 0.  Yet calling code does prevent `n < 2`.  3)  Lesser compilers will recalculate `sqrt(n)` repeatedly. 4) `sqrt(n)`  can fail to correctly test with large `n` that exceed precision of `double` when `sqrt()` is weakly implemented - that point is now more rare.  All in all, still the answer is a good attempt. UV

Comment: @chux Edited for labs(), thank you. All the other stuff - this is not the question the OP asked. What the calling code imposes is not really important, the utilitarian function should be well behaved. And -1 is not a prime. But please feel free to edit this implementation. There are tons of much better prime-testers....

Comment: > I'd expect all n<0 to return 0.< Why so?? Mathematically, that is wrong. Of course we could force unsigned behavior right on, but IMHO it would lessen the educational value of answers.

Comment: > Lesser compilers will recalculate sqrt(n) repeatedly.< Really? In the conditional of a for loop? With a clearly unchanging n? Have you ever seen a compiler that won't pull that out of the loop? I have not, since the mid-80ies.

Comment: [Can negative numbers be prime?](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html) and [Do we have negative prime numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1002459/83175) well discuss the negative prime issue.  I edited code as prior code could incur `sqrt(some_negative)` leading to UB.  Note that `labs(LONG_MIN)` is UB.   "Have you ever seen a compiler that won't pull that out of the loop?" --> Yes.  Compilers for embedded processors - which tend to be less robust.

Comment: @chux Thank you for pointing out theses issues. Indeed, since I'm coming back to C from a long time ago, it appears that a lot of things have changed. Currently very unhappy with the FP treatment of things like division by 0 or square root of negative numbers. And yes, labs(LONG_MIN) bombs - bloody 2's complement. Well, I will have to rethink a lot of things. BTW, my original code did not die on negative inputs to sqrt() - because of the implicit conversion of NaN to an integer. Very insidious behavior....

Comment: Welcome back.  The biggest "things have changed" is compilers exploitation of _undefined behavior_.  Code like `(INT_MAX + 1)*0` and `abs(INT_MIN)` is no longer acceptable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183052/discussion-between-germannerd-and-chux).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 9872349871 is a very large number - too big to fit into an `int`. When you convert it from a string to an `int` it gets truncated and you get 1282415279 instead.

This can be easily seen if you convert the numbers into hex...

> 9872349871 is 24c701aaf in hex
>
> 1282415279 is  4c701aaf in hex

So instead of using `int` for your `n` and inside your `isprime` function you should use something that can take bigger numbers, like a `long`

```
long n = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
```

The programming exercise you are following should have indicated what range of inputs your code should be able to cope with, so you would be able to anticipate issues like this.

Comment: `long` is not guaranteed to be able to represent numbers larger than `int`, nor guaranteed to be able to represent numbers larger than can fit in 32 bits.

Answer (score -3):

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int isprime(long long n) {
    for (long long i = 2; i != n; ++i)
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf ("Usage: p4 <number>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char* p;
    long long n = strtoll(argv[1], &p, 10);
    if (n < 2 || *p != '\0')
    {
        printf ("input wrong\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int result = isprime(n);

    if (result == 1)
        printf ("%lld is prime\n", n);
    else
        printf ("%lld is not prime\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should work and yet it doesn't - it has the same bug as the OP's code

Comment: @ChrisTurner fix it

Comment: Your "fix" does nothing.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *The atoi, atol, and atoll functions convert the initial portion of the string pointed
to by nptr to int, long int, and long long int representation, respectively.
Except for the behavior on error, they are equivalent to
atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10) [...]*

Comment: @EOF Where is wrong? run like `./a.out 123`, it's OK.

Comment: Try running it with "9872349871" like in the question

Comment: @ChrisTurner @EOF My wrrong, use `long long` fix it

Comment: @YunbinLiu, it works very good, but not for "9872349871" when I use with gcc and ./a.out 9872349871 and it's nothing showing until I suspensed to try again with 1, 3, 9... the output for 1 is wrong input, 3 is prime and 9 is not prime, but nothing for 9872349871.

Comment: @DevinMorlan test `./a.out 9872349871` output : `9872349871 is not prime`

Comment: That what I run all your code but it's not working as I sent you the link.

Comment: I am not sure how you get the output but mine isn't working... It has to be exact "9872349871" should be not prime.

Comment: @DevinMorlan run ` ./a.out 9872349871` and wait, maybe it need more time

Comment: Got it... Now this is what I received..https://ibb.co/ceMQhf it said is 9872349871 is prime.

Comment: @DevinMorlan Why?

Comment: According to GCC compile, that's what it said prime... It should be not prime.