# Getting an infinite running program when using scanf

Tags: c, netbeans, scanf

I'm getting an infinite running programm when I use the following code to read a string from keyboard and save it within a structured vector.

`scanf("%s", strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung, (int)sizeof(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung - 1));`

Simply nothing happens after this line is reached and the program runs infinitly.

I know `scanf()` isn't recommended. We're using it only within our C beginners course and I want you to keep it in mind, ie please don't recommend other function rather than above mentioned for the moment.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int nummer;
    char bezeichnung;
    int menge;
    float preis;
} artikel;

void eingabe_artikel(artikel *strk_zgr_fp, int i_fp);
void ausgabe_artikel(artikel *strk_zgr_fp, int i_fp);

void main(void) {
    artikel artikelliste[10];
    artikel *strk_zgr;

    int anzahl;

    do {
        printf("Bitte eine #Artikel eingeben [<= 10]: ");
        scanf("%d", &anzahl);

        if(anzahl < 1 || 10 < anzahl)
            printf("\nEs wurde eine falsche #Artikel eingegeben.");
    } while(anzahl < 1 || 10 < anzahl);

    for(int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
        eingabe_artikel(&artikelliste[i], i);

    int i;
    for(strk_zgr = artikelliste, i = 0; strk_zgr < artikelliste + anzahl; 
        strk_zgr++, i++)
        ausgabe_artikel(strk_zgr, i);
}

void eingabe_artikel(artikel *strk_zgr_fp, int i_fp) {
    printf("\nBitte den %d. Artikel eingeben: ", ++i_fp);

    printf("\nNummer: ");
    scanf("%d", &strk_zgr_fp->nummer);

    printf("Bezeichnung: );
    scanf("%s", strk_zgr_fp, (int)sizeof(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung - 1));     /* <-- */

    printf("Menge: ");
    scanf("%d", &strk_zgr_fp->menge);

    float preis;
    printf("Preis: );
    scanf("%f", &preis);
    strk_zgr_fp->preis = preis;
}

void ausgabe_artikel(artikel *strk_zgr_fp, int i_fp) {
    printf("\n%d. Artikel: ", ++i_fp);

    printf("\nNummer:\t%d", strk_zgr_fp->nummer);
    printf("\nBezeichnung:\t%s", strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung);
    printf("\nMenge:\t%d", strk_zgr_fp->menge);
    printf("\nPreis:\t%.2f EUR\n", strk_zgr_fp->preis);    
}
```

[NetBeans Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyg4C.png)

[Complier Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfqqE.png)

Comment: you can't scanf into a structure. you must scanf into a structure member.

Comment: also `scanf("%s", one, two);` has 1 argument too many.

Comment: and you really should check the return value of scanf (and most functions with prototype in `<stdio.h>`): `if (scanf(...) != EXPECTED_ASSIGNMENTS) /* error */;`

Comment: You're not checking if `scanf()` actually worked.

Comment: I understand you're still learning, so I just want to make sure you understand an additional, important lesson here: the problems you're having are precisely *why* it's often recommended to avoid using `scanf`.  `scanf` turns out to be a poorly-defined function.  It doesn't work well, it's hard to use correctly, it's difficult if not impossible to do more sophisticated things with it.  Experienced C programmers don't use it at all; it's only ever used by beginners.  But since it's so hard to use, beginners *always* have problems with it.

Comment: If introductory C textbooks and beginning C instructors stopped teaching C programmers to use `scanf`, C would be much easier for beginners to learn.

Comment: One big problem with the loop that reads an integer using `scanf("%d", &anzahl);` is what happens when you enter something that doesn't start with optional whitespace followed by optional +/- sign, followed by a digit. In that case, `scanf` will return 0 and the input stream will be left at the position of the non-digit character. So when you go round the loop again, that non-digit character is still there and it will fail in exactly the same way.

Comment: (At)Steve: Thanks for your comment. I'm aware of the issues regarding obsolet scanf() function. The C course is written back in 2009, anyway not even in the early C days. However, I'd like to follow all the examples. Unfortunately, they're using this poorly-defined function.

(At)Ian: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to keep your recommondation in mind whenever I'm facing that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems in the code. Please at least fix the missing ending quotes on the printf() calls.

Now to the beef:

1) Your structure is wrong. 'Bezeichnung' is defined as a single character, not a string.

```
typedef struct {
   int nummer;
   char bezeichnung[100];
   int menge;
   float preis;
} artikel;
```

2) You cannot use scanf() in the way you did. If you want to limit the input length (which always is a good idea), you need to pass the maximum length into the format string.
Do you nee to use scanf()?? Because it gets messy from here on....
As your maximum input length might be variable or subject to change (see 1.), you need to build the format string for scanf. Something like this:

```
char format_str[15];
format_str[0] = '%';
//Dont use itoa(), it is not C standard.
sprintf(&format_str[1], "%d", (int)sizeof(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung) - 1);
strcat(format_str, "s");
scanf(format_str, strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung);
```

Hope that gets you going.

PS: You need to include string.h for strcat().

Comment: Alternative to `char format_str[15]; ... strcat(format_str, "s");` --> `char format_str[1+20+1 +1]; 
sprintf(format_str, "%%" "%zu" "s", sizeof(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung) - 1);`

Comment: Are you following me? ;) Anyhow, why this: format_str[1+20+1 +1]; ?

Comment: Your good solution in 3 lines of code can simply be done tighter with 1 `sprintf()`.  I suggested a larger buffer size (1 for %, 20 to handle all sizes up to 2^64, 1 for s, 1 for \0) as 15 seemed unclear to its origin.

Comment: @chux OK, I see what you are doing. When I try to write code for obvious newbies, I try to write it in a way that is easily understandable to them. That might mean inelegant code...But isn't the purpose of answering questions to help people understand better? Same goes for the prime algorithm. And, yes, 15 was completely arbitrary.

Comment: Re: "Same goes for the prime algorithm" --> Not following you - [just coincidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53106001/2410359) as we apparently have common interests.

Comment: Concerning 'tightness' of code: Of course, as a C coder I appreciate that. However, within the context of the OP's question it is clear that he/she does not understand formatting strings for the scanf/printf family of functions. Why make it unnecessary hard for them? I intentionally wrote code that broke everything down to small bits... And anyhow, there is always the question about terse code vs. explicit code. This translates to (human) readability. After so many decades coding in different languages, I'd say: Human readability is paramount. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: (At)GermanNerd: Thanks for your answer. 1) My fault, in the example code there's a string defined instead of a single character. 2) I'll try it out and let you know, if it fixes my issue.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked fine for me. Not sure on this sprintf() function. Could you please explain why I'm supposed to use it? By now, I used this code:
`char format_str[20];
    format_str[0] = '%';
    strcat(format_str, "s");
    printf("Bezeichnung: ");
    scanf(format_str, strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung);`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. There was another example which I did and the course leader provided a scanf() function like this to read a string: `scanf("%s", &(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung));`. I thought when I'm reading a string the address operator isn't used. The only difference is the address operator now is used and the element was put into brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried it out and it worked fine for me. Not sure on this sprintf() function. Could you please explain why I'm supposed to use it? By now, I used this code: char format_str[20]; format_str[0] = '%'; strcat(format_str, "s"); printf("Bezeichnung: "); scanf(format_str, strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung);

While that works, you are missing out on limiting the length of the user's input. That is why I proposed using sprintf() to create a (sub)string containing the maximal allowable length of the user input, depending on how large your 'bezeichnung' is defined in the struct. Suppose 'bezeichnung' has a limit of 100 characters, you would want to limit the input to 99 (+1 for the zero-termination), so you want a scanf format string like this: "%99s".

chux has provided a much more compact version of my three lines, but I think, in the beginning, you will have it easier to just assemble such format strings piece by piece, at the same time learning how to a) change individual characters in a string, how to use sprintf() in a basic way, and how to concatenate strings with strcat().

> There was another example which I did and the course leader provided a scanf() function like this to read a string: scanf("%s", &(strk_zgr_fp->bezeichnung));. I thought when I'm reading a string the address operator isn't used. The only difference is the address operator now is used and the element was put into brackets.

Now, I think this is bad practice. It works, but is superfluous. Consider this small code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test{
    int i;
    char a_str[10];
};

int main()
{
    struct test a_test;
    printf("Normal array adress taking: %p\n", a_test.a_str);
    printf("Using '&' to take adress of array: %p\n", &(a_test.a_str));
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.